# Replace fragment only without passing data

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to get my second list fragment to open, but with the imperfect code below it thinks that I want to pass data from the DummyContent to show 'Item x' when I actually don't. What needs to change in the if and/or else statements so that the list fragment opens rather than 'Item x' appearing? I know that `ARG_ITEM_ID` is the culprit but I don't know what to change it to.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    if("1".equals(id)){
        if (mTwoPane) {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            ContinentsListFragment fragment = new ContinentsListFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.item_list, fragment)
                    .commit();

        } else {
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ContinentsListActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(ContinentsListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems too easy but let's start understanding the issue.
Sample code fix:

```
Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ContinentsListActivity.class);
startActivity(detailIntent);
```

Notes:

- Code with putExtra is removed.
- If you insist on calling putExtra, make ContinentsListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID **static** access or use any accessible constant, technically.